# Subnet aks-subnet is in use and cannot be updated (AKS)

Tags: kubernetes, dns, azure-aks

we have a couple of aks cluster running with stop start automation almost over a year now. Today all clusters failed to start (failed state, Failed (Running)) with the following message:

> Failed to start the Kubernetes service 'CLUSTERNAME'. Error: Reconcile
> VNet failed. Details: VNetReconciler retry failed: Category:
> ClientError; Code: Unspecified; SubCode: InUseSubnetCannotBeUpdated;
> Message: ; InnerMessage: ; Dependency:
> Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks; OrginalError:
> Code="InUseSubnetCannotBeUpdated" Message="Subnet aks-subnet is in use
> and cannot be updated." Details=[]; AKSTeam: Networking, Retriable:
> false.

We didn't change anything and we are not using a custom subnet (default kubenet). Google isn't helpful here either (stackoverflow, github, mailinglist), there no topics which are helpful right now. Manual start via Azure UI leads to the same error.

Cluster was created with

```
az aks create -n $CLUSTER_NAME ^
--resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP ^
--enable-aad ^
--enable-azure-rbac ^
--disable-local-accounts ^
--location $LOCATION ^
--node-count 1 ^
--node-vm-size Standard_D2s_v3 ^
--load-balancer-sku basic ^
--node-osdisk-size 30 ^
--node-osdisk-type Managed ^
--kubernetes-version 1.22.1
```

The basic sku public ip address shouldn't be a problem until 30 September 2025.
Kubernetes Versions is out of support, 1.22.4 is currently beeing used but we can't updated it nowsince the cluster doesn't start in the first place. I don't think this is the issue though.
To clarify this didn't happen after a kubernetes update the Cluster has been running fine with 1.22.4 already.

Can anyone help here or maybe has the same issue?

Best
Simon

Answer (score 0):

that happen to me yesterday. I execute this command and the cluster got back on line

```
 az resource update  -n mycluster -g myResourceGroup --namespace Microsoft.ContainerService --resource-type ManagedClusters
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This command apparently is working for some but not for us we got the following error msg:  

(InternalOperationError) Operation failed after exceeding the maximum retry count.
Code: InternalOperationError
Message: Operation failed after exceeding the maximum retry count.